# Android animation - how add start margin?

Tags: android, android-animation

I am trying to make animation of group of buttons sliding in and out but I am struggling with one problem.
Current animation is moving correctly but is sliding out from the very left of the screen. Just where is the button used to show up this. So this makes whole animation looks bad, because this group is sliding on this.

What I want to achieve is add some margin, or something similar that will make start of the animation just from the point where is the button.

I want it to look like this:

[image: margin]

That means those 3 images will start showing from this white line, not from the very left of the screen.

Main activity `onCreate`, where everything is going on:

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        image1 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.imageLayout);
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonShow);

        animationSlideInLeft = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, 
                R.anim.push_right_in);
        animationSlideOutRight = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, 
                R.anim.push_left_out);
        animationSlideInLeft.setDuration(1000);
        animationSlideOutRight.setDuration(1000);
        animationSlideInLeft.setAnimationListener(animationSlideInLeftListener);
        animationSlideOutRight.setAnimationListener(animationSlideOutRightListener);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if(v == button)
                {
                    if(!on)
                    {
                        curSlidingImage = image1;
                        image1.startAnimation(animationSlideInLeft);
                        image1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        on = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        image1.startAnimation(animationSlideOutRight);
                        image1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        on = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

animations files:

**push_right_in**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="300"
        android:fromXDelta="-100%p"
        android:toXDelta="0" />

    <alpha
        android:duration="300"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />

</set>
```

**push_left_out**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="300"
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:toXDelta="-100%p" />

    <alpha
        android:duration="300"
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.0" />

</set>
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonShow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Btn" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/imageLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/icon" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/icon" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/icon" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code:

```
TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(-50, 0, 0, 0);
anim.setStartOffset(0);
anim.setDuration(3000);
imageView.startAnimation(anim);
```

Hope it Helps!!

Comment: Percentages are useless in Android.

Comment: @sebap123 try this edited code and reduce xdelta value as per your requirement.

Comment: @ArmaanStranger can you show it in code, because animations are added using `AnimationUtils.loadAnimation`

Comment: use as i have showed you in code. create animation and startanimation for any view.

Answer (score 0):

You can add Padding to the parent Relative layout in this case the animations starts from padding like this

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingRight="64dp">
```